# How can we loop through child node in JSON data in c#

Tags: c#

I have written a c# code to pull the JSON data through HTTPREQUEST. The json data has multiple child node inside the parent node. 
Below i have attached a sample JSON data format and the code which I built to loop through node. My code only check 1st level of child node (there will be child inside the child node).

1. Any one please help me to alter the code to loop through multiple child nodes.
   2.Also I want apply delay of 1 mins after each web request.

   ```
   HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url.com/api/section);
       httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
       httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
       try
       {
           using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
           {
               Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
               StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
               str4 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               streamReader.Close();
               responseStream.Close();
           }
           foreach (forumsec.forumsec forumsec in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<forumsec.forumsec>>(str4))
           {
               long id = forumsec.id;
               TableOperation operation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge((ITableEntity)new forumsecEntity(id.ToString())
               {
                   pid= forumsec.pid,
                   name = forumsec.name,
                });
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://https://url.com/api/section?parentid=" + id.ToString());
       httpWebRequest1.ContentType = "application/json";
       httpWebRequest1.Method = "GET";
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
               using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest1.GetResponse())
                   {
                       Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                       StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                       str4 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                       streamReader.Close();
                       responseStream.Close();
               foreach (Childcategories forum in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Childcategories>>(str4))
                   {
                       long caid = forum.categoryid;
                       TableOperation operation1 = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge((ITableEntity)new ChildcategoriesEntity(caid.ToString())
                       {
                           pid = forum.pid,
                           name = forum.name

                       }
                   }                   
                   }
           }
   ```

JSON file format

```
{
ID: 123
Name: BACD
ParentID: 
Children: [
        ID: 765
        Name: atdr
        ParentID: 123 
        Children: [ 
                    ID: 098
                    Name: jryr
                    ParentID: 765
                    Children: []
                    ]
        ]
```

Comment: you have made 8 questions and never accepted an answer

Comment: Apologies, accepted the answer

Comment: Can't you get the full json output at the first http request?

Comment: @VishanthaPeiris No, I was getting data of top node. I solved issue by looping the process until last node.